# Trouble with list surviving through recursion in python; finding all possible routes on a graph

Tags: python, list, recursion, graph

I'm writing a python program that takes a fully connected graph (you can go to any node on the graph from any other node) and finds all possible routes on that graph that are shorter than a given maximum distance.

This is what I've coded thus far:

```
def find_all_routes (cur_node, graph, willing_to_travel, visited, routesdict):
    """ Finds all routes possible within a certain distance.
    inputs
        cur_node: a dictionary with n entries, each of which is the distance to the nth
            dictionary in graph.
        graph: a list of n dictionaries, each of which contains n entries, each of which
            is the distance to the nth item in the list.
        willing_to_travel: the maximum distance we are willing to travel.
        visited: initialized as an empty list, will be populated nodes we've been to.
        all_routes: initialized as an empty list.
    Affects:
        all_routes is populated with every route permutation that can be traveled in under willing_to_travel distance.
    """
    #Add our current location to the visited list.
    for i in cur_node:
        if cur_node[i] == 0:
            visited.append(graph[i])

    # Add the current route to the dictionary.
    entry_no = len(routesdict)
    routesdict[entry_no] = visited
    print ("routesdict", routesdict)            # Just for diagnostic purposes.

    # Recursion with other nodes we can reach as the new start node.
    for i in cur_node:                               # For every place in the dictionary
        if graph[i] not in visited:                  # if we have not been there
            if cur_node[i] <= willing_to_travel:     # And if we can afford to go there
                find_all_routes(graph[i], graph, willing_to_travel - cur_node[i], visited, routesdict)

    return routesdict

def main():

    graph = [
        {0: 0.00, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.10},
        {0: 0.12, 1: 0.00, 2: 0.22},
        {0: 0.10, 1: 0.22, 2: 0.00}]

    max_distance = 10.0
    been_to = []
    routesdict = dict()

    routes = find_all_routes (graph[0], graph, max_distance, been_to, routesdict)

print ("Final output: ", routes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output from this is:

```
routesdict:    {0: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}]}
routesdict:    {0: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}], 1: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}]}
routesdict:    {0: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}, {0: 0.1, 1: 0.22, 2: 0.0}], 1: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}, {0: 0.1, 1: 0.22, 2: 0.0}], 2: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}, {0: 0.1, 1: 0.22 , 2: 0.0}]}
Final output:  {0: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}, {0: 0.1, 1: 0.22, 2: 0.0}], 1: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}, {0: 0.1, 1: 0.22, 2: 0.0}], 2: [{0: 0.0, 1: 0.12, 2: 0.1}, {0: 0.12, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.22}, {0: 0.1, 1:0.22, 2: 0.0}]}
```

Which is ugly as heck, but to reword it in terms of the nodes we are visiting, it is going like this:

```
routesdict [0]
routesdict [0, 1] [0, 1]
routesdict [0, 1, 2]  [0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2]
Final out: [0, 1, 2]  [0, 1, 2] [0, 1, 2]
```

For a three node graph, if maximum distance is sufficiently high to complete every possible route I would like the output to look a bit more like this:

```
All possible routes*: [0], [0,1], [0,1,2], [0,2], [0,2,1]
*If we must start at node 0.
```

===============

Now, I think I see the problem, but I can't quite think through solving it. The issue is that I am keeping the identity of the list "visited" rather than ripping out the current value of "visited" and then moving on with it.

So the first time through the recursion, routesdict[0] is defined as "visited" and it correctly has node [0] as the first route. But when visited is changed, routesdict[0] is updated, and now it says [0,1].

This is the same thing that is preventing the function from doing the recursion I want it to, which is why it's giving me three possible routes instead of the five I expect.

So, is there a nice way to keep my "visited" list while going into deeper recursions, but not have the list retroactively apply to the rest of the world?

Thanks for reading!

*Edit:*

I've already solved the problem with getting routes into routesdict by changing the line to

```
routesdict[entry_no] = visited[:]
```

But I'm much more clueless about not having the visited list break my recursion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your problems are caused by the same thing: Python passes lists by reference, not by value.

First, what that means, in brief:

When you call `foo(a)` with `a` as an int, inside `foo()` you just get the value of `a`, not its actual location in memory. You have `a` written on your paper, and you show `foo()`, "This is `a`, write it down."

However, when you call `bar(b)` with `b` as a list or object, you are not getting the value of `b`, you are getting `b` itself, the memory location. You still have `b` on your paper, but you say to `bar()`, "Hey, `b` is pretty complicated and probably not worth copying to a new sheet of paper. You can just share my paper." This is great for keeping your programs from being really slow, but -- as you are experiencing -- it means that any changes `bar()` makes to `b` change `b` everywhere.

To solve your problems, you should pass copies of the objects that you don't want to be changed. You already figured this out when adding `visited` to `routesdict`, but you should actually just do

```
find_all_routes(graph[i], graph, willing_to_travel - cur_node[i], visited[:], routesdict)
```

This means that every call to `find_all_routes()` gets its own, personal copy of `visited`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Very clean answer. I just couldn't quite get my brain around it. It's a bit frustrating that I was working at it for hours trying to get it working when I just needed three key presses, but hey, that's life!

Comment: Totally. That's why it's a good idea for anyone planning to make a career of programming to work on a low level language at some point. You start to see a lot of things that you didn't before.